# German quotation marks are broken in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, punctuation, babel

Although I known nothing about German, I have to complie some German TeX documents. The German quotation marks `"'` or `\grqq` and `"'` or `\grqq` in my document are replaced by cmr font and the PDF file is not copyable near the quotation marks. A warning message says

> font shape `OT1/TeXGyrePagella(0)/m/n' undefined, using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead for symbol `glqq' on line 9.

The following is my minimal example:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont{TeXGyrePagella}
\begin{document}
These are German \glqq quotation marks\grqq.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Never use `babel` with XeLaTeX. For internationalization support use [`polyglossia`](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) instead. Besides, in this case it's not even needed. You can
enter the quotation marks either using ASCII symbols or direct UTF-8:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures = TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}

<< >> ,, ``

« » „ “

\end{document}
```

`polyglossia` also has some `babel` shorthand support to ease the transition from `babel`.

Comment: Simply great answer!

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: Hi, in the meantime `babel` supports XeTeX too, maybe you like to add this to you answer :-)

Answer (score 8):

**Update (March 2016)**
`babel` now supports XeTeX so the following will work:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\begin{document}
These are German \glqq quotation marks\grqq.
These are German "`quotation marks"'.
\end{document}
```

---

**Original Answer**
Think you’d better use polyglossia instead of babel:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\newcommand\glqq{"`}
\newcommand\grqq{"'}
\begin{document}
Thess are German \glqq quotation marks\grqq.
Thess are German "`quotation marks"'.
\end{document}
```

(I changed the font …)

Comment: Yes, I known such a package and advise. I've tryed it but not succeed. My code was essential the same with yours, the error msg says !missing number, treated as zero <to be read again>\l@german...

Comment: @Ma “essential the same” means not identical, right? Could you provide the minimal example that gives this error? Maybe it’ll help to update your TeX-system first.

Comment: @Ma Ming: an error is normal during the first run of XeLaTeX after you change from babel to polyglossia. It's caused by an annotation in the `.aux` file and is to be ignored; it won't happen any more.

Comment: @Tobi Finally I figure out I need `etoolbox` to support `polyglossia`.

Comment: @Ma Do you mean, that `polyglossia` requires `etoolbox`?

Comment: @Tobi Yes, `polyglossia` relies on `etoolbox`.

Answer (score 2):

When using babel you should check if the language definition files you want to use are already adapted to the unicode engines -- this isn't the case for a number of non-western scripts -- but with (n)german it will work fine with xelatex. You are not getting the quote because xunicode doesn't provide the necessary definitions. It is easy to add them. E.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\DeclareUTFcharacter[\UTFencname]{x201C}{\grqq}
\DeclareUTFcharacter[\UTFencname]{x201E}{\glqq}

\begin{document}
These are German \glqq quotation marks\grqq.
\end{document}
```

Also take a look at the package `csquotes`

(Edited on march 2016 to adapt to the new commands in fontspec and the development in babel.)

Comment: Hi, in the meantime babel supports XeTeX too, maybe you like to add this to you answer :-)

Comment: @Tobi: I never wrote that babel doesn't support xetex. Actually the answer says explicitly that with ngerman ist works fine. The question is always only which of the language files have already support for the unicode engines. But I will update a bit the answer to adapt to the changes.

Comment: Ups … sorry :-) Actually I only read the first line of you answer before posting my comment O:-)